How to get the height function for modular lattices?
In these notes, it is said that for modular lattices of finite lengths the height function
\begin{gather*}
h(x)=lub\{l(C):C=\{x_0,...,x_n:x_0=O\prec...\prec x_n=x\}\}
\end{gather*}
obeys
\begin{gather*}
h(a\wedge b)+h(a\vee b)=h(a)+h(b)
\end{gather*}
and I'm not sure how to get that. An infimum $O$ exists by assumption so modularity gives relations like
\begin{align*}
O\preccurlyeq a&\implies O\vee(b\wedge a)=(O\vee b)\wedge a=a\wedge b &\\
O\preccurlyeq(a\wedge b)&\implies O\vee(a\wedge(a\wedge b))=(O\vee a)\wedge(a\wedge b)=a\wedge b &\\
a\preccurlyeq(a\vee b)&\implies a\vee(O\wedge(a\vee b))=(a\vee O)\wedge(a\vee b)=a &
\end{align*}
but I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

@user14111 Yes, fixed. Thank you.

In the notes you link to, there's the result

Theorem. The following conditions on a lattice of finite length are equivalent
[my note: equivalent to others above, but in particular to each other]

In $L$, $a$ and $b$ cover $a\wedge b$ iff $a\vee b$ covers $a$ and $b$;
The height function $h$ in $L$ obeys $h(a\vee b) + h(a\wedge b) = h(a) + h(b)$.


There is this result in [1], Ch. IV §2

Theorem 2. Let $L$ be a lattice of finite length.
The following conditions on $L$ are equivalent, for $a,b,c \in L$:

(...)
If $a \neq b$ and $a$ and $b$ cover $a\wedge b$, then $a\vee b$ covers $a$ and $b$.
(...)
$h(a) + h(b) \geq h(a \wedge b) + h(a \vee b)$.


Now, the first condition in the first theorem implies the second and its dual in the second, whence, by (2) equivalent to (4) in the second, both the lattice and its dual satisfy
$$h(a) + h(b) \geq h(a \wedge b) + h(a \vee b).$$
But the dual lattice satisfying the above condition is equivalent to the original satisfying
$$h(a) + h(b) \leq h(a \wedge b) + h(a \vee b),$$
and therefore we have the equality.

Update.
Better than the above, just use Corollary 3 in the same chapter and section of the referenced book:

Corollary 3.
Let $L$ be a lattice of finite length.
The following conditions on $L$ are equivalent:

$L$ is modular.
(...)
$h(a) + h(b) = h(a \wedge b) + h(a \vee b)$



[1] George Grätzer, General Lattice Theory, second edition, Birkhäuser, 2003

I think I got it, thanks. And in a modular lattice $a\vee b$ always covers $a$, right?

@user9871234 No, it doesn't. Not even in a distributive lattice, or even Boolean. For example, in the powerset of ${a,b,c,d}$, the join of ${a,b}$ and ${c,d}$ is ${a,b,c,d}$ which covers none of them; likewise, none of them covers their meet, which is the empty set.

Thx, I see why this is not true now by looking at a diagram. Two more questions if you may?
(1) Where is the mistake below?
Suppose $a\prec c\prec a\vee b$. By modularity $a\vee(c\wedge(a\vee b))=(a\vee c)\wedge(a\vee b)$ and $a\vee((a\vee b)\wedge c)=(a\vee b)\wedge c$ and since $(a\vee c)\wedge(a\vee b)=(a\vee b)\wedge c$ implies $(a\vee c)\wedge(a\vee b)\preccurlyeq(a\vee b)\wedge c$, we take the meet on both sides and get $a\preccurlyeq a\wedge c$ which yields $a=c$ (contradiction).
(2) How does "$a$ and $b$ cover $a\wedge b$ iff $a\vee b$ covers $a$ and $b$ imply the height result?

Sorry I forgot to mention I don't own the book you are referencing (I'm using whatever online notes I can find).

@user9871234 (1) $a \preceq a \wedge c$ does not imply $a=c$; indeed, from $a \prec c$, we get $a \wedge c = a$, so the above just yields the trivial result $a=a$. (2) I'm not sure if I understood. Are you asking for a proof of Theorem 2? I could do that, but it will take me a while.

I see my mistake in (1). I also got (2) (yes, I was asking for the implication as I thought it followed a bit more easily than it does). Thanks again.

@user9871234 I still don't understand. Is it something you were asking but now no more? Or are you still asking something, and in that case, what?

"Is it something you were asking but now no more?" Yes, sorry for the confusion.
